# MySQL Workbench unable to backup connections

Tags: backup, mysql, connection, mysql-workbench

I tried to take backup from connections through tools from top menu, however I received this error which I have no idea how to get rid of it. Do you know how to solve it?

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZvTT.jpg):